# How to increase likes & dislike properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button on every post

1)  Like button

if user has already liked the post then unlike button is shown

here is the HTML part if user hasn't like the post

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="liker" data-count="0" data-fpc="481" data-id="cDJod1RnUU45eXBQWmp">Like</a>
```

if user has already liked the post

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="unliker" data-count="1" data-fpc="481" data-id="cDJod1RnUU45eXBQWmp">Unlike</a>
```

here is the jquery part, this part send for like request

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#liker", function() {
        var t = $(this).data("id"),
            a = $(this).data("count"),
            f = $(this).data("fpc");
        a++;
        $("#cyli" + f).text(a);
        $(this).attr('id', 'unliker');
        $(this).data('count', a);
        $(this).text('Unlike');
        i = this, $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/liker?io=" + t,
            data: "id=" + t,
            success: function(t) {}
        })
    });
});
```

below part send unlike request

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#unliker", function() {
        var t = $(this).data("id"),
            a = $(this).data("count"),
            f = $(this).data("fpc");
        a -= 1;
        $("#cyli" + f).text(a);
        $(this).attr("id", "liker");
        $(this).data('count', a);
        $(this).text("Like");
        i = this, $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/unliker?io=" + t,
            data: "id=" + t,
            success: function(t) {}
        })
    });
});
```

Like value is shown in this tag `<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="cyli481" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp; 0</i>`

Now the problem is when i click on like or unlike the value isn't properly added or deducted.

for e.g if data-count="0" this means there is no like on this post but when i click on it becomes automatically 2 and then if i click on unlike button it become -1 what could be wrong in above method

Comment: Why don't you simply replace `a++` & `a-=1` by `a=1` & `a=0` ? It's not perfect and it doesn't answer your question, but it does solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you just change the `$(this).data("count")` and `$(this).data("count", a)` to `$(this).attr("data-count")` and `$(this).attr("data-count", a)`.

Try this code:

```js
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#liker", function() {
        var t = $(this).data("id"),
            a = $(this).attr("data-count"),
            f = $(this).data("fpc");
        a++;
        $("#cyli" + f).text(a);
        $(this).attr('id', 'unliker');
        $(this).attr('data-count', a);
        $(this).text('Unlike');
        i = this, $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/liker?io=" + t,
            data: "id=" + t,
            success: function(t) {}
        })
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#unliker", function() {
        var t = $(this).data("id"),
            a = $(this).attr("data-count"),
            f = $(this).data("fpc");
        a -= 1;
        $("#cyli" + f).text(a);
        $(this).attr("id", "liker");
        $(this).attr('data-count', a);
        $(this).text("Like");
        i = this, $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/unliker?io=" + t,
            data: "id=" + t,
            success: function(t) {}
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="liker" data-count="0" data-fpc="481" data-id="cDJod1RnUU45eXBQWmp">Like</a>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="cyli481" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp; 0</i>
```